# Why do the error occurs adding legend to plot?

Tags: r, plot, classification, raster, shapefile

I'm trying to add the legend to my classification map using the code below.

```
library(raster)
library(RStoolbox)
landsat5 <- stack('lt05.tif')
shp<-shapefile("to5/to.shp")
SC_rf <- superClass(landsat5, shp, responseCol = "MC_ID",
                    nSamples = 1000, polygonBasedCV = TRUE,
                    model = "rf", tuneLength = 5, kfold = 5,
                    mode = "classification", predType = "raw", overwrite = TRUE)
## Plots
colors <- c("yellow", "green", "deeppink", "orange", "red")
plot(SC_rf$map, col = colors, legend = TRUE, axes = FALSE, box = FALSE)
legend(1, 1, legend = levels(shp$MC_info), fill = colors , title = "Classes")
```

The map is created but a legend error occurs:

> 'legend(1, 1, legend = levels(shp$MC_info), fill = colors, title = "Classes")':
>     'legend' is of length 0

Here is my **shp** object:
[image]

Comment: `shp$data$MC_info`?

Comment: Doesn't help, still gives the same error

Comment: yes, in both cases gives _'legend' is of length 0_

Comment: From the image, `shp` doesn't have a cell named `MC_info`. `MC_info` is in `shp$data`. Does `shp$MC_info` return anything? And what is its class?

Comment: `shp$MC_info` no longer shows the error but still doesn't show legend. And shp has SpatialPolygonsDataFrame class

Answer (score 1):

`MC_info` seems to be a vector, not a factor, so you don't need to use `levels()`. To access data in shapefile object, try to convert it by `as.data.frame()` function from `raster` package:

```
legend(1, 1, legend = raster::as.data.frame(shp)$MC_info, fill = colors , title = "Classes")
```

Or you can define a variable for that:

```
shp_df <- raster::as.data.frame(shp)
legend(1, 1, legend = shp_df$MC_info, fill = colors , title = "Classes")
```

This works for me as it converts the `data` data frame from the `shp` object and the `MC_Info` column is easily accessible. But I don!t have your data to check the legend working properly as you need...

Comment: It no longer shows the error but still doesn't show names from MC_info but only numbers 1-5 from MC_ID...

Comment: @Aisyram I'm quite not familiar with spatial polygons, but you can try to supress the default legend in `plot()` like `plot(..., legend = FALSE)` to let the legend() take effect? See [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RStoolbox/versions/0.2.6/topics/superClass) at the bottom. Let me know if that works...

Comment: @Aisyram Hi, I tried to play around with shapefile objects and it seems to me that to access its data, you need to use `as.data.frame()` function from `raster` package. I have updated the answer, try this, please, and let me know.

Comment: Still the same... But i found another solution:
`par(xpd = FALSE, mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1))
plot(SC_knn$map, col=colors, breaks=brk, main="K-Nearest Neighbors Classification", legend = FALSE, axes = FALSE, box = FALSE)
par(xpd = TRUE)
legend( "right", legend = c("Woda", "Zabudowa miejska", "Roślinność niska","Grunty", "Drzewa"), 
        fill = rev(colors), inset = -0.5, cex = 0.8, title = "Klasy:",title.adj = 0.1)`
Isn't perfect but quite works.